# How to use c program directly in any web server?

Tags: c, webserver

I have a small program written in c and i am planning to convert it to a web service module. Is there any web server(Linux or Windows platform) where i can embed the c program directly. I googled and found some of the web servers which supports c code are **Apache, mongoose** etc. But i don't know how to implement it?

Comment: If you dont know it, you have to learn it: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/apache/ch15_01.htm

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for CGI. See the docs for more info:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html

Answer (score 2):

G-WAN is one of the fastest Web Servers, and it supports running C-programs directly (gwan.com). It's much faster on multi-core CPUs than other webservers.
Basically, you can just run any C/C++ (or many other) files just by placing them in /csp directory.

Answer (score 1):

http://monkey-project.com/ is able to do what you want and probably the simplest solution to your problem. http://gwan.com/ might also be interesting, depending on what exactly you want to do.